# Why doesn't the # of unread messages ever shrink?

Tags: feature-request, support

I've noticed that despite being fairly current with my StackExchange threads, my number of unread posts in the red circle keeps climbing. The number never goes down.

Is there a StackExchange(tm) MagicPairOfEyes(tm) tool that I need to use?

I've had to resort to using the "Notify [bleep] daily of any new answers" feature so that I know when my threads are updated.

Edit on 4/8/2011:

I've been working under the premise that reading the posts in their natural habitat should be enough to decrement the counter. For example, now that I've read your post, I expected the counter to go down the next time I refresh the page.

In my perfect world, I'd be able to catch up on a couple of threads by clicking on the red dot and then come back later, click the same dot, and read some more threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clicking the logo with the red circle should cause the counter to reset, under the assumption that you are now *reading* the unread messages.

Is this not happening for you? Have you tried clearing your browser cache if so?

Comment: Ah, I've been working under the premise that reading the posts in their natural habitat should be enough to decrement the counter. For example, now that I've read your post, I expected the counter to go down the next time I refresh the page.